# C/C++ Posix tcp/ip network client, only connecting to localhost

Tags: c++, sockets, posix

I was writing this simple client on Ubuntu 12.  It is simple C/C++ connect to server code.  It  works connecting to localhost.  But I can't get it to connect to an outside server.  Everytime I connect to a different host, it actually connects to 'localhost'.  I am thinking it might be the way my /etc/hosts file is configured but I don't know.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int connect(const std::string host, const std::string path) {
    const int port = 80;
    // Setup the msock
    int m_sock;
    sockaddr_in m_addr;
    memset(&m_addr, 0, sizeof(m_addr));
    m_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    int on = 1;
    if (setsockopt(m_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*) &on, sizeof(on)) == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    // Connect //
    m_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    m_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    int status = inet_pton(AF_INET, host.c_str(), &m_addr.sin_addr);

    cout << "Status After inet_pton: " << status << " # " << m_addr.sin_addr.s_addr << endl;
    if (errno == EAFNOSUPPORT) {
        return false;
    }
    status = ::connect(m_sock, (sockaddr *) &m_addr, sizeof(m_addr));
    if (status == -1) {
        return false;
    }
} // End of the function //
```

At this line: m_addr.sin_addr.s_addr

I get zero.

Comment: what do you send as host? Domain or Ip ? 
inet_pton is used just for converting the IP address from string to number.

Comment: connect(reddit.com, 80);   Maybe that is the issue.

Comment: OK, that helps.  What do you think, close the question or do you want to answer it?

Comment: use : `gethostbyname` to resolve the ip address first .

Comment: Can you create a valid answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first resolve the IP address of your Domain name from DNS server then try to establish the connection . 
`gethostbyname` will give the list of IP address which resolved from the Domain name with the `hostent` structure . you can use it as follow :

```
struct hostent *hent;
hent = gethostbyname(host.c_str());
```

Then move over the list of address hostent give you and test the connection,here is the `hostent` structure and `gethostbyname` definition :

```
#include <netdb.h>
struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *name);

struct hostent {
  char  *h_name;            /* official name of host */
  char **h_aliases;         /* alias list */
  int    h_addrtype;        /* host address type */
  int    h_length;          /* length of address */
  char **h_addr_list;       /* list of addresses */
}
```